# Laravel getting belongsTo through intermediate table

Tags: php, laravel

consider the following database scheme:

```
companies
    -- id
    -- name

logos
    -- id
    -- active
    -- company_id
    -- image_id

images
    -- id
    -- filename
    -- path
    -- type
```

Then I have relationships in models defined this way:

**Company.php**

```
public function logos() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Logo');
}
```

**Logo.php**

```
public function image() {
    $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Image');
}
```

And now I want to get specific company based on its id with its logos and images. So I tried to fetch it this way, but it throws the error:

> Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

**CompanyController.php**

```
public function show($id) {
    $company = Company::findOrFail($id);
    $requester = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();
    if( !$requester->hasRole('noc') && $requester->company_id != $company->id) {
        return $this->response->errorUnauthorized("You have no rights to view this company profile.");
    }

    // I am trying to fetch it this way //
    $company->logos;
    foreach ($company->logos as $logo) {
        return $logo->image;
    }
    return $this->response->array(compact('company'))->setStatusCode(200);
}
```

Could anyone help me? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$company = Company::with('logos.image')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: doesn't work, throws: `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`

Comment: That's because you've forgot to add `return` to the `image` relation.

Comment: :D yes, I'm noob! Thanks :), I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes :)